# How to stack columns in a pivot in Sas

Tags: datatable, sas, pivot-table

The Data looks the following way:

```
Name    Date     Car     Bus     Taxi   Auto
Adam    9_2023    15      0     -30     85
Adam    10_2024   25     -26     27     0
Adam    11_2025   0       10     15     0
Luke    8_2023   -5       5      67     20
Luke    9_2023    30     -45     0      0
Luke    10_2024   20      0      90    -15
Luke    11_2025   0       0      0      0
```

I need to make it into a pivot table where the Name is in rows, Date in columns and Car, Bus, Taxi, Auto in  values. The output should look this way:

```
       Car                                   Bus                                   Taxi                                   Auto      
Name   8_2023   9_2023   10_2023   11_2023   8_2023   9_2023   10_2023   11_2023   8_2023   9_2023   10_2023   11_2023   8_2023   9_2023   10_2023   11_2023
Adam   0        15       25        0         0        0       -26        10        0       -30       27        15        0        85       0          0
Luke  -5        30       20        0         5       -45       0         0         67       0        90        0         20       0       -15         0
```

I have tried the following:

```
proc tabulate data = test out=output;
class Name Date;
var Car Bus Taxi Auto;
tables Car*Date Bus*Date Taxi*Date Auto*Date;
run;
```

This gives me the output data as:

```
Date      _TYPE_   _PAGE_   _TABLE_   Car_Sum   Bus_Sum   Taxi_Sum   Auto_Sum
8_2023     1        1        1        -5        5         67         20     
9_2023     1        1        1         45      -45       -30         85
10_2023    1        1        1         45      -26        117       -15
11_2023    1        1        1         0        10        15         0
```

i have also tried the following:

```
proc tabulate data = test out=output;
by Name;
class Date;
var Car Bus Taxi Auto;
tables Car*Date Bus*Date Taxi*Date Auto*Date;
run;
```

This does give the result in the desired format but in the result tab and as seperate table for each name.

One way of solving this might be to create a unique combination of date and the vehicle type for eg: 8_2023_Car 9_2023_Car and so on but I can't seem to come up with the logic.

I need it in an ouput since I need the table to do further joins.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I gave a thumbs up and I'm waiting for answers...

Comment: Do you want a REPORT or a DATASET?  What report did the PROC TABULATE generate? Does it not meet your reporting needs?

Comment: @Tom - I need a data set, as I need to further join the resultant table to other tables. The proc tabulate in the second case gave me the tables in the 'result' tab and there were two tables, one each for Adam & Luke. I need it in a single table.

Comment: The listing you showed as the desired output is NOT a dataset. It does not have unique variable names (column headers).

Comment: @Tom - Thats why I said that one way might be to create a unique column header such as: 8_2023_Car 9_2023_Car ... 11_2023_Auto but I am not able to come up with a logic to do that. Hence asking for help.

Comment: I can show you a simple way to flatted your dataset, but WHY? do you want it?  It is mush harder to use data in that shape.

Comment: @Tom - any help is appreciated. It is a small piece of a bigger project so I need it in a dataset.

Comment: I would like to see how these further joins are coded.  Far better to reshape the joining data as well so a statement such as  `BY name month year vehicle_type` could be used.

Answer (score 1):

First create your date values as date values.  And do not display them in Month-Year order because they will not sort properly.  Display them in Year-Month order.

```
data have ;
  input Name :$8. Date :anydtdte. Car Bus Taxi Auto;
  format date yymm7.;
cards;
Adam    9_2023    15      0     -30     85
Adam    10_2024   25     -26     27     0
Adam    11_2025   0       10     15     0
Luke    8_2023   -5       5      67     20
Luke    9_2023    30     -45     0      0
Luke    10_2024   20      0      90    -15
Luke    11_2025   0       0      0      0
;
```

To flatten that data you first need to make it taller so that it is normalized.

```
proc transpose data=have out=tall ;
  by name date;
  var car bus taxi auto;
run;
```

And if you want the resulting variables ordered by name instead of date then resort the data.

```
proc sort;
  by name _name_ date;
run;
```

Now you can flatten the data to one observation per NAME.

```
proc transpose data=tall out=want(drop=_name_) delim=_;
  by name;
  id  _name_ date;
  var col1;
run;
```

[image]

The Y2023M08 values appear at the end because the first BY group did not have that date.  If you want those to appear in order you need to square-up the data to have all dates for all names.

Comment: Thanks Tom! just one issue that its actually a very large input data set, like 1000 rows so can't manually input. I already have it in a dataset form in Sas. That shouldn't be an issue right?
Again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Should not matter, other than if DATE is a character string it is more likely to have inconsistent values. Like like representing September of 2023 as both 9_2023 and 09_2023 on different observations.

Answer (score 0):

The double transpose will pivot your data into the shape you want to shackle ourself with.  However, the ordering of the metadata and completeness of the new structure is dependent on the data values present.

Sometimes you need to construct an ordered coverage of the data values across all groups (i.e. the dates across all names) so that the across-ness after the pivot is not in scattered clumps.

Example:

A dummy first record (basis) is constructed that covers the reasonable pivot data situations and orders them accordingly. The final data set will have missing values where a name did not have a record for a date.

```
data have; input
Name $  Date  $  Car     Bus     Taxi   Auto; datalines;
Adam    9_2023    15      0     -30     85
Adam    10_2024   25     -26     27     0
Adam    11_2025   0       10     15     0
Luke    8_2023   -5       5      67     20
Luke    9_2023    30     -45     0      0
Luke    10_2024   20      0      90    -15
Luke    11_2025   0       0      0      0  
Luke    12_2026   0       0      0      0  
;
data stage1;
  set have;
  by name notsorted;
  month_part = input (scan(date,1,'_'),best.);
  year_part  = input (scan(date,2,'_'),best.);
  if first.name then name_seq + 1;
run;
proc contents noprint 
  data=have 
  out=col_order (keep=name varnum type 
                 where=(name not in ('Name', 'Date') and type=1)
                );
proc sort data=col_order; by varnum;
proc sql noprint;
  create table date_coverage as
  select distinct year_part, month_part
  from stage1;
  select name into :numvars_colordered separated by  ' ' from col_order order by varnum;
proc sql;
  create table basis(label='Shape basis') as
  select
    0 as name_seq
  , '0' as name length=25
  , year_part
  , month_part
  , colorder.name as _name_ length=32
  , 0 as col1
  from colorder
  cross join date_coverage
  order by varnum, year_part, month_part
  ;
proc transpose data=stage1 out=stage2;
  by name_seq name year_part month_part;
  var &numvars_colordered;
proc append base=basis data=stage2;

proc transpose  delimiter=_ 
  data=basis 
  out=want(drop=_name_ where=(name_seq ne 0) ) 
;
  by name_seq name;
  id month_part year_part _name_;
run;
```

[image]